# How can you view ASP.NET Session State in a different platform like PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, session-state

Say I have an ASP.NET webpage and I also have a PHP Blog/BBS/Website.  I want all logins to be done via the ASP.NET webpage.  The ASP.NET Session State is stored in SQL.  Is there any way I can read/decode the Session State from PHP to tell if a user is logged on if I have the Session State cookie?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a supported way. You could reverse-engineer the store, but the database format may change with next .NET service pack and youe a'd be screwed then.

The only safe way would be to implement your own session state provider so you could guarantee that the database format doesn't change.

If all you need is to verify that the user is authenticated, it would be probably easier to send the user an encrypted cookie with the username and decrypt it in the PHP app.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this but if you provided a simple web service that is part of your asp.net application but only accessable from your PHP site. You should now be able to read anything that is in session via the web serivce.

Answer (score 0):

this is looks tricky, but try reading [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). the issue here is know the way in what asp encodes and save the session, if you can read that format, this may help.

another way I'm thinking is to create a request to some "login" page form asp to php, where you send the login credentials and the php file creates the session, but this could be not secure if you leave it open, and also could be slow, since another request is necessary.

on the other hand I saw few sites, where once you are logged in, for example in the main site and you want to go to the forums, you click on some link that submit a form to the php login page (credentials are "harcoded" for that user in that session) and the php page login you like the "regular" behavior.

hope to be clear

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need full access to the entire asp.net session state, you may be better off just storing the particular pieces of information that you know both apps need to share in a shared database or file directly.

That way you can ignore most of the complexities of an asp.net session and just pick and choose the specific pieces data your apps need share with each other.